# Tableview not loading/triggering

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have the following single view app. The tablview delegate/datasource are connected to the Root View Controller through IB.  When the app loads, the tableview is empty.  I've set a breakpoint in all methods of the ViewController.swift file and nothing is hit.

[image]

I have added the following in ViewController.swift (UITableViewDataSource is also there now):

```
UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "just a cell"
    return cell;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

Since no breakpoints are getting hit in ViewController.swift, I think something is still not connected.  Any ideas what this might be or what I'm doing wrong?

The project has just the stock Single View app files:

[image]

-- EDIT --

Cell identifier updated but still no data in the table.

[image]

Below is the connection from the tableveiw to the Root View Controller.

[image]

Comment: Is the reuse identifier of the UITableViewCell prototype in Storyboard set to 'test'?

Comment: Is that the same as Restoration ID?  Than yes.  If no - where do I find that setting?

Comment: The tableView is empty (no cells), or the cells have nothing in them?

Comment: The cells have nothing in them.  I can see the horizontal lines separating each cell.

Comment: When you say, no breakpoints are hit, does that include viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 problems:

#### 1. ViewController class not correctly assigned in IB

When your Root View Controller is selected, what appears here in the right hand pane? It should be ViewController (the name of your ViewController class) like this:

[image]

Note that IB won't let you select a class which is not a `UITableViewController` subclass. If you have an empty Storyboard and drag out a Navigation Controller, the Root View Controller it creates is a Table View Controller, and it will only let you associate that with a `UITableViewController` subclass. If you really don't want to use a `UITableViewController` you have to delete the Root View Controller that IB created for you, drag out a regular View Controller, add in the Table View and then hook everything up as necessary by hand.

#### 2. Outlets not correctly wired up

The way you've hooked up the outlets doesn't look right. The `UITableView` should have outlets `dataSource` and `delegate` referencing the RootViewController. Like this:

[image]

Whereas the RootViewContoller should have **referencing** outlets dataSource and delegate referencing the Table View.

From the the *crash* you're getting (`[UINavigationItem tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`) it's clear that you have hooked up the dataSource and delegate to the navigation bar, not the View Controller (the yellow circle Storyboard hierarchy view).

Comment: I've added a new pic to the OP showing the IB connections from tableview to rootviewcontroller.  I did also add UITableViewDataSource to ViewController.swift.  Still no data in the tableview.

Comment: When you created your RootViewController in IB, did you create it as just a `UIViewController` or as a `UITableViewController` ?

Comment: UIViewController.  I then added the tableview on top in IB and adding the delegate/datasource to the ViewController.swift file.

Comment: That's almost certainly where things went wrong. Your RootViewController has to either be a subclass of `UITableViewController` or it has to explicitly implement the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: It does explicitly implement the protocols, as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Hooking up the dataSource and delegate is not explicitly implementing the protocols. The OP only mentions `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Sorry - that was in a comment just above.  I have also updated the OP.

Comment: Where is that screenshot coming from?  If I remove the connections to the top yellow Root View Controller box and instead go from tableview to the Root View Controller, I get a SIGABRT when the app starts.

Comment: Ctrl-click on the Table View in IB.

Comment: Mine is the same except for Master, I have "Root V..."

Comment: Edited my answer: is your table view also hooked up to a property in your VC? UITableViewController does this by default, others don't.

Comment: Can you explain your last sentence in your answer?  How is that done?  Also, in regards to the crash, here is why: -[UINavigationItem tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ok, it looks like you've hooked up the dataSource and delegate to the navigation bar, not the VC, hence `UINavigationItem` in the crash.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by this: "...property of your VC also". Which property are you referring to?

Comment: A `UIViewController` has a property `view` which is it's main `UIView`.  A `UITableViewController` has a property called `tableView` to point to its `UITableView`. In your case, your VC's `view` property is probably pointing to your table view, so you should be fine. This is not what's causing the problem. See the other edit I made to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72942/discussion-between-mluisbrown-and-4thspace).

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Identifier** in Storyboard - it should say *test* where I have *switchCell*. You'll find it in the bar on the right side by clicking on the prototype cell:

[image]

Comment: I have added this but still not data in the table. OP updated.

Comment: Just to be sure - put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()` to see if the ViewController is even loaded.

Comment: It does not load.  Breakpoints in ViewController.swift aren't getting hit.

Comment: In that case you need to connect the ViewController class to the view in Storyboard.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by that or supply steps?  The tableview is connected to the RootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the cell inspector the style of your prototype cell is "Custom". Such a cell does not have a textLabel. Switch the style to Default and you will get a UITableViewCell that has a `textLabel`.

And since it's obviously an error if there is no textLabel you should replace `textLabel?` with `textLabel!`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    cell.textLabel!.text = "just a cell"
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean style "Custom"?  I don't see Default.  Basic doesn't change the behavior.  Still no data. Replacing "?" with Bang, no change either.

Comment: Basic sounds correct. There is not much more in that method that can go wrong. If nothing is showing you should check if this method is even called. Put a breakpoint inside or add a `println("cellForRowAtIndexPath")`

Comment: I previously mentioned that none of the methods in ViewController.swift are being called.  So the tableview is still disconnected from the app for some reason.